# Property 'id' does not exist on type 'FormComponent'

Tags: angular, typescript, forms

Below is my form, I don't know why he can't identify "id" in the first `*ngIf="id.invalid"`

```
<form [formGroup]="personneForm" (ngSubmit)="afficherTout()">
    <div>
        Identifiant :
        <input type="number" formControlName="id">

        <div *ngIf="id.invalid">
            <div *ngIf="id.errors?.required">L’identifiant est obligatoire</div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div>
        Nom :
        <input type="text" nama="nom" formControlName="nom">

    </div>
    <div>
        Prenom :
        <input type="text" formControlName="prenom">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!personneForm.valid">Envoyer</button>
</form>
```

and this is my form.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl,FormGroup,Validators } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.css']
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
  personneForm = new FormGroup({
    id: new FormControl("",Validators.required),
    nom: new FormControl("", [Validators.pattern(/ˆ[A-Z][a-z]{2,10}/),
    Validators.required]),
    prenom: new FormControl("",[Validators.pattern(/ˆ[A-Z][a-z]{2,10}/),
    Validators.required])
    });
    
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.personneForm.controls.nom.valueChanges.subscribe(change => {console.log(change);})
  }
  afficherTout(): void {
    console.log(this.personneForm.value);
    }
}
```

I tried `personneForm.id` or `this.id` but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Ahmed, it's looks like you forget make a getter

```
get id(){
   return this.personneForm.get('id')
}
```

Yes, in Angular the variables you use in the .html should be or variables or getter in .ts

Another way is use in your .html

```
<div *ngIf="personneForm.get('id').invalid">
   <div *ngIf="personneForm.get('id').errors?.required">
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh I see, I "get" it now ! 
Thanks Eliseo